# react - redux: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a redux reducer that handles the login and logout of the user. The login works perfectly, the logout gives the following error:

```
loginReducer.js:60 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at loginAPIReducer
```

Currently, my code looks like this:

//logouttypes:

```
export const LOGOUT_REQUEST = "LOGOUT_REQUEST";
export const LOGOUT_SUCCESS = "LOGOUT_SUCCESS";
export const LOGOUT_FAILURE = "LOGOUT_FAILURE";
```

//logoutactions:

```
import {LOGOUT_REQUEST, LOGOUT_SUCCESS, LOGOUT_FAILURE } from './logoutTypes'


export const logoutRequest = () => {
  return{
    type: LOGOUT_REQUEST
  }
}

export const logoutSucces = response => {
  return{
    type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
    payload: response
  }
}

export const logoutFailure = error => {
  return{
    type: LOGOUT_FAILURE,
    payload: error
  }
}
```

// reducer:

```
export const startLogout = () =>{
  
  
  return dispatch => { 

    dispatch(logoutRequest)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(logoutSucces)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(logoutFailure(error))
    })
  }
}




const loginAPIReducer = (state = initialLoginState, action) => {
  console.log(action.type)
  switch(action.type){
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return{
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return{
        loading: false,
        user: action.payload,
        error: '',
        logedIn: true
      }
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return{
        loading: false,
        user: '',
        logedIn: false,
        error: action.payload
      }
    case LOGOUT_REQUEST:
      return{
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return{
        loading: false,
        user: '',
        logedIn: false,
        error: ''
      }
    case LOGOUT_FAILURE:
      return{
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default loginAPIReducer;
```

the startLogout function is called in the navbar:

```
<Button variant="outline-success" onClick={startLogout}>Log out</Button>
```

The reducer is connected to the store. As stated above, the code doesn't show any problems with the login, but the logout, which is the mirror of the login function, gives the abovementioned error.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `type` inside your actions to the reducer.
as you see the error says `property type is not defiend`.

```js
export const startLogout = () =>{
  
  
  return dispatch => { 

    dispatch(logoutRequest()) // passes: { type: LOGOUT_REQUEST }
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(logoutSucces(res))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(logoutFailure(error))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what the logoutRequest function does? Namely it returns: {
    type: LOGOUT_REQUEST
  }

Comment: ‍`logoutRequest` is a function so if you want the result then you should call it. Please just test it

Comment: Currently no success. The only way I solved it (for now) is by dispatching one type explicitly from the mapDispatchToProps, but that seems to defeat the entire purpose of having a layered approach, namely: request, success or fail. ```const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      // dispatching actions returned by action creators
      logout: (e) => dispatch({type: 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS'}),
    }
  }```